# PHP MySQL connection: (HY000/2026): SSL connection error

Tags: php, mysql, ssl

I'm getting an error when trying to connect to MySQL with SSL. I get this error:

> mysqli::real_connect(): (HY000/2026): SSL connection error

I'm able to successfully connect with Sequel Pro with the following settings:

[image]

Note that it doesn't require any certificate files, only that it connects with SSL.

Here is my PHP connection attempt:

```
$mysqli->ssl_set(NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 'DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:AES128-SHA');
$isConnected = $mysqli->real_connect('10.10.0.7', 'myuser', 'mypassword', '', '3306', NULL, MYSQLI_CLIENT_SSL);
```

This results in the above error. All the examples I've read use certificates, yet this server doesn't seem to require them explicitly since I can connect with Sequel Pro without them.

Here are the results of `SHOW STATUS LIKE 'Ssl_cipher';` for the MySQL server:

`DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA`

I've tried that in the `ssl-cypher` option with the same results.

Where can I find more detailed logging about what is actually breaking here, or what can I do to try and connect?

EDIT: This is PHP 5.3.3.

Comment: Does your host have a valid TLS Certificate?

Comment: Uncheck "Connect with SSL" unless you change the host to a URL. SSL does not work with an IP address for host.

Comment: `show variables like '%ssl%'` confirms that the server has certs for `ssl_ca`, `ssl-cert`, and `ssl_key`. However my Sequel Pro connection does not require them (only the SSL checkbox), and I'd like to configure PHP to not require them either if possible.

Comment: We do use a domain, I tried to obscure connection details in the image and used an IP.

Comment: Also, I am trying to debug the PHP connection. The Sequel Pro connection works fine. I'm only including it as proof that I can connect without a certificate using that tool.